# is there any way to resolve appendchild xss flaw of veracode in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I have a function where I append a script element with appendchild

```
 setconfig=function(w,d,s){
    var j=d.createElement(s);
    j.src='scripts/init.js';
    j.setAttribute("onload",_scriptonload);
    d.body.appendChild(j);
}
```

This d.body.appendchild is causing veracode xss flaw (improper neutralization of script-related html tags in web page )

I tried below code , which resolved the veracode code flaws but is not supported in IE and breaks the functionality.

```
 setconfig=function(w,d,s){
    var j=d.createElement(s);
    j.src='scripts/init.js';
    j.setAttribute("onload",_scriptonload);
    const bodyelem=d.body;
    bodyelem.appendChild(j);
}
```

is there any approach which will resolve both things.